# In Matlab 2019b/2020a, when building a DNN, how to reshape the output of a fully connected layer to 2D shape so that a pretrained CNN can follow?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I am using the Deep Learning Toolbox to design a deep neural network. In the network, a 2D convolutional layer needs to follow a fully connected layer. But the deepNetworkDesigner doesn't allow such a structure because the output of a fully connected layer is 1D. In other frameworks like Torch, the way to solve it is to reshape the output of a fully layer to be 2D. Is there a method to achieve it Matlab 2019b/2020a? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are creating your network without using the Deep Learning Network Analyzer

You can do this by creating a fully connected layer with an output size of 10 and the name 'fc1'

```
layer = fullyConnectedLayer(10,'Name','fc1')
```

Then, by including it in your Layer array

```
layers = [ ...
imageInputLayer([28 28 1])
convolution2dLayer(5,20)
reluLayer
maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
fullyConnectedLayer(10)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer]
```

As you can see, the fully connected 2D layers were followed by a fully connected layer of size 10 with no problems.

> As the name suggests, all neurons in a fully connected layer connect
> to all the neurons in the previous layer. This layer combines all of
> the features (local information) learned by the previous layers across
> the image to identify the larger patterns. For classification
> problems, the last fully connected layer combines the features to
> classify the images. This is the reason that the output size argument
> of the last fully connected layer of the network is equal to the
> number of classes of the data set. For regression problems, the output
> size must be equal to the number of response variables.

Then, you can finish up your network by creating the layer graph as `lgraph = layerGraph(layers)`

---

### If you have already designed your network using the Deep Network Designer

You can export the network's architecture to the workspace, and modify its output layer in two ways:

**1. Using the GUI**

- In the Designer pane, drag a new `fullyConnectedLayer` from the Layer Library onto the canvas. Set `OutputSize` to the number of classes in the new data
- Delete the last fully connected layer and connect your new layer instead
- if your goal was to develop a classification network, replace the output layer. Scroll to the end of the Layer Library and drag a new `classificationLayer` onto the canvas. Delete the original output layer and connect your new layer instead
- Check your network by clicking Analyze. The network is ready for training if Deep Learning Network Analyzer reports zero errors.

**2. Without using the GUI**

- On the Designer tab, click Export. Depending on the network architecture, Deep Network Designer exports the network as a LayerGraph `lgraph`
- Replace the final layer by the one using
  `newlgraph = replaceLayer(lgraph,the layer you want to change, the desired new layer)`
- Use `analyzeNetwork(newlgraph)` to check if the network is ready for training. If so, the Network Analyzer has to report zero errors.